topic [/talker] does not appear to be published yet
I try to run the following code on ROS Kinetic
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Float64

def publishMethod():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('talker', Float64, queue_size=10) # defining the publisher by topic, message type
    rospy.init_node('publish_node', anonymous=True) # defining the ros node - publish node 
    rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz # fequency at which the publishing occurs
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        publishFloat = 32.0 # varibale 
        rospy.loginfo("Data is being sent: %f", publishFloat)  # to print on the terminal 
        pub.publish(publishFloat) # publishing 
        rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        publishMethod()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException: 
        pass

But I received an error "topic [/talker] does not appear to be published yet".
The pictures of the 3 terminals and the bashrc file is as as follows

How can I solve the error?
